# DSM results from WebODM are not correct

Tags: dem, terrain, orthophoto, photogrammetry, ground-control

I am new to WebODM and I am trying to generate DSM and Orthomosaic images using default settings in WebODM.

The Orthomosaic image is correct by providing GCP but the DSM file is having inaccurate elevations when compared to google earth.

I am not sure what went wrong or is there any way/configurations in WebODM to have a better DSM generated.

---

I don't know what parameters should I use for better results so I keep the input parameters Default or DSM + DTM.
I'm attaching a GCP table, screenshot of DSM, Orthophoto, and input parameters, so can you please suggest to me what changes should I made to input parameters for getting better output.

GCP table:
+proj=utm +zone=44 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
357783.55   3120786.54  0   5178.90 1405.57 DJI_0001.JPG    gcp16
357783.55   3120786.54  0   5162.22 2005.07 DJI_0002.JPG    gcp16
357783.55   3120786.54  0   5142.58 2778.84 DJI_0003.JPG    gcp16
357804.03   3120770.86  0   4262.03 1258.89 DJI_0001.JPG
357762.67   3120667.30  0   4948.59 2184.14 DJI_0007.JPG
357777.35   3120672.63  0   5355.83 1863.45 DJI_0007.JPG
357754.61   3120678.37  0   4503.34 1714.50 DJI_0007.JPG
357760.16   3120490.52  0   3624.37 1034.95 DJI_0016.JPG
357731.51   3120529.78  0   4986.50 1891.50 DJI_0016.JPG    gcp15
357743.91   3120519.01  0   4411.38 1939.29 DJI_0016.JPG

[image: Screenshot of Orthophoto]
[image: Screenshot of DSM]
[image: Screenshot of GCP table]

Comment: There are many ways things could have gone wrong and you should provide more focus to your question.  How is your surface different from Google Earth and why do you assume GE is 'more correct'?  Maybe your surface model has a different vertical datum. Maybe your GCPs are incorrect or your units of measure are different than GE.  Please post your GCP table, maybe a copy of the surface model if possible, and a screen shot of the WebODM input parameters.

Comment: Going to have to echo GBG. Google Earth is a product mostly aimed at visualization. Hyper-local accuracy is not a goal, nor something they test for. You'd be best to compare your surface to local benchmark elevations, or hopefully local government data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Saijin_Naib and GBG. Can you please suggest what parameter should i use for better DSM results.